# Android create activity automatically?

Tags: android

I want to develop an **e buy** application. I have categories and sub-products and data is kept in external server. If I add a new category on the server I want to add category and product activity automatically. Is it possible? How can I create a new activity automatically and how can I add the activity automatically in the android manifest?

Comment: that is practically impossible

Comment: Most of the time, what you would do is modifying the views. You can hide certain element on the view upon triggered while append new elements into that view.

Comment: you can change the look of activity by modifying it at runtime, but you cant do create a new activity

Comment: firstly I thought a table for every category in database. if I have one table for all products and query them which needed it is easier for me.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) objects **must** be declared at compile-time and cannot be changed later. You must adapt your code to work in the different situations.

For example, let's say you are fetching a name, birthdate, and description for a human resources entry. You would create one `Activity` that contained your layout and [text fields](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), then have that `Activity` fetch the name, birthdate, and description from your server. It would then populate the text fields with the data, or show/hide the fields if there is no data for them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a design issue, the activity should not be binded with your data. You should design an activity for categories data and an activity for products data. If they have different look, just build different sub class of your root activities.